# How to print al list of user one by one with complete information in linux using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I have started writing a small piece of code to print all the list of users available in the linux box. But I want to pass one by one user into my command to display each user details together.

#### to list all users

```
root@bt# getent passwd | grep /home/ | cut -d ':' -f 1

root
san
postgres
```

Now I want to pass one by user in to the below command to display each user details together.

```
root@bt# chage -l ${user1} ; chage -l ${user2} etcc.
```

should I need to user for loop or while loop here? 
can any one help me in suggesting how to write the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `while` loop:

```
getent passwd | grep /home/ | cut -d ':' -f 1 | \
  while read user ; do
    chage -l "$user"
  done
```

or the `for` loop:

```
for user in $(getent passwd | grep /home/ | cut -d ':' -f 1) ; do
    chage -l "$user"
done
```

or `xargs`:

```
getent passwd | grep /home/ | cut -d ':' -f 1 | \
  xargs -n1 chage -l
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `xargs`, which runs a command on each output item of the previous pipe:

```
getent passwd | grep /home/ | cut -d ':' -f 1 | sudo xargs -I % sh -c '{ echo "User: %"; chage -l %; echo;}'
```

- `sudo` is used to get information about all users, if you don't have access to this information then you can remove `sudo`
- `-I %` is used to specify that `%` is a placeholder for the input item (in your case a user)
- `sh -c '{ command1; command2; ...;}'` is the command executed by `xargs` on every `%` item; in turn, the command `sh -c` allows multiple shell commands to be executed
- '{ echo "User: %"; chage -l %; echo;}' echoes the current user in `%`, then runs `chage -l` on this user and finished with a final empty `echo` to format the ouput

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) I think if i would like to print User name before every chage command, we may need to user loop instead of xargs, I'm i correct ??

Comment: That is possible without a `for`-loop. I edited my answer so it prints the users.